How can I sculpt on the new face after bisecting?
I bisected my mesh, then added a face from the cut edge. I am unable to use the sculpting tools on this new face. I assume the face needs to be modified before I can sculpt on it?
In the attached picture, see the area I bisected.  Any and all help appreciated.


I discovered that if I right-click, and convert to mesh, I can then sculpt.
